# Hodge diamond of complete intersections

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose we have a smooth complete intersection of hypersurfaces with degrees $d_1,...,d_r$ in some $\mathbb{P}^N$. This should be a surface and in certain situations a surface of general type. What can one say about the Hodge diamond? Or what is its Grothendieck group ?

Comment: So are you assuming $r = N - 2$ since you say you get a surface?

Answer (score 10):

This question is addressed in Appendix I of [Topological Methods in Algebraic Geometry](http://books.google.com/books?id=KC4cBQqhhb0C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). Let $V_n^{d_1, \ldots, d_r}$ denote the complete intersection of $r$ generic hypersurfaces of degrees $d_1, \ldots d_r$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n + r}$. Let

$$
\chi_y(V_n^{d_1,\ldots, d_r}) = \sum_{p,q \geq 0} (-1)^qh^{p,q}(V_n^{d_1,\ldots, d_r})y^p = \sum_{p \geq 0} \chi^p(V_n^{d_1,\ldots, d_r})y^p
$$

where $y$ is an indeterminate and $h^{p,q}$ are the Hodge numbers and

$$
\chi^p(V_n^{d_1,\ldots, d_r}) = \sum_{q \geq 0} (-1)^qh^{p,q}(V_n^{d_1,\ldots, d_r}).
$$

Then Theorem 22.1.1 of the above reference says that

$$
\sum_{n \geq 0} \chi_y(V_n^{d_1,\ldots, d_r}) z^{n+r} = \frac{1}{(1-z)(1 + zy)}\prod_{i=1}^r\frac{(1 + zy)^{d_i}-(1-z)^{d_i}}{(1+zy)^{d_i}+y(1-z)^{d_i}}.
$$

This let's you compute the numbers $\chi^p(V_n^{d_1,\ldots, d_r})$ which aren't exactly the Hodge numbers. However, the next Theorem makes it possible to find the actual Hodge numbers from this data. Thereom 22.1.2 in the same section says that

$$
h^{p,q}(V_n^{d_1,\ldots, d_r}) = \delta_{p,q} \enspace \enspace \text{for} \enspace \enspace p + q \neq n,
$$

$$
\chi^p(V_n^{d_1,\ldots, d_r}) = (-1)^{n-p}h^{p,n-p}(V_n^{d_1,\ldots, d_r}) + (-1)^p \enspace \enspace \text{for} \enspace \enspace 2p \neq n
$$

and

$$
\chi^m(V_n^{d_1,\ldots, d_r}) = (-1)^mh^{m,m}(V_n^{d_1,\ldots, d_r}) \enspace \enspace \text{for} \enspace \enspace 2m = n
$$

Comment: So, this computation based on Lefschetz hyperplane theorem?

Comment: Yes. In particular, the computations of theorem 22.1.2 use Lefschetz hyperplane theorem. The argument for packaging them together into the generating function of theorem 22.1.1 uses Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch to relate that generating function to the Chern classes.

Answer (score 1):

The Grothendieck group/ring tensor $Q$ is the same as the Severi-Chow group/ring tensor $Q$, which varies a lot when you vary your hypersurfaces. This happens already in the case of algebraic surfaces in $P^3$.

Comment: Can you give an explicit example of this phenomena?

Comment: Well, take a look of surfaces of degree 4 in P^3. Configurations of curves on them can be vastly different (for example, some of them contain lines, (which are rigid -- can not be moved), while most surfaces of degree 4 have no lines on them. Thus their Picard (= Neron-Severi, in this case) lattices will be diffenet, and thus their K-groups are different.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small (Python) program which computes Hodge numbers of hypersurfaces;

It is very easy to modify to work for complete intersections, too.

It contains references (to Hirzebruch and Deligne) in the comments section, and also a couple of examples in dimensions two and three:

[Link, at the GitLab](https://gitlab.com/maxim.leyenson/hodge-numbers-of-hypersurfaces)